# Implementing dropdown from database (ngFor)

Tags: angular, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to implement a dropdown menu that takes values from my database.

Here's how I have it working without a dropdown (as an input box):

```html
...
<form class=form-group>
<td><label>Origin</label></td>
<input type="hidden" #Origin (ngModel)="Origins" value="{{Origins}}">
</form>
...
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="addDetails(...,Origin.value,...">Add</button>
```

I tried using a static dropdown and it worked. Heres the code I used:

```html
<div class="form-group">
<select class="form-control">
<option #Origin (ngModel)="Origins" value="HRRJK">HRRJK</option>
</select>
</div>
```

However when I try to use ngFor like this:

```html
<div class="form-group">
<select class="form-control">
<option *ngFor="let CodeListPort of port" #Origin (ngModel)="Origins" value="{{CodeListPort.codeListPortID}}">{{CodeListPort.codeListPortID}}</option>
</select>
</div>
```

it **does populate the dropdown with the appropriate values from the database**[image]
 however when I try to submit it, it results with the following error:

```
Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong?
I'm pretty sure that everything is ok in the ts file (since the values actually come to the dropdown) but if it helps I can post it on request.

If this is not the right approach please suggest an appropriate solution.

**Solution edit:**

The code I used to get it working is the following:

```html
<div class="form-group">
<select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="Origins" name="Origins" #Origin>
<option *ngFor="let CodeListPort of port" value="{{CodeListPort.codeListPortID}}">{{CodeListPort.codeListPortID}}</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Unfortunately I couldn't use [ngValue] (which would allow use of dynamic data) as @SrAxi answered because the button that executes the addDetails function needs the parameter to be "value".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, try with this:

```
<select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="Origins" name="Origins" #Origin>
    <option *ngFor="let CodeListPort of port" value="{{CodeListPort.codeListPortID}}">{{CodeListPort.codeListPortID}}</option>
</select>
```

So, what we did here is move `ngModel` to the `select` tag. When you get the select's model it will return you the selected option.

Comment: Unfortunately this results in an error: "{"Origin":["The Origin field is required."]}". I get an identical result if I use the input code and submit without entering anything. Any ideas?

Comment: @ire remove the `#Origin` from the select and try it out. If you are not using the `#Origin` for anything in particular you don't need it. You can reference the value of the select by the `ngModel`

Comment: Got it working! The issue was that I actually needed [ngValue] to be value because if you look at the 1st snippet, the button for executing the code uses the parameter "value". Thank you so much. This was driving me crazy.

Comment: I'm glad it worked! Great! So, you just removed `#Origin`, right? And you used `[ngValue]` in the `option` right?

Comment: See the solution edit at the bottom of the main post for my clarification. You can edit your answer to the first state because that might help someone else make a better solution.

Comment: @ire great! Makes sense. I'm glad I was useful. Good luck coding! ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143665/discussion-between-ire-and-sraxi).